# Android Play Console new Crash reports shows only first 10 lines

Tags: android, google-play

In Android Play Console crash reports shows only first 10 lines of log. I can't see the rest of log. I attached the screenshot.
Related Gradle settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetSdkVersion 25
  multiDexEnabled true
} 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Updated analytics library and sdk version to latest, didn't help

Answer (score 1):

you either use latest buildToolsVersion or change `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'`
 to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```